# What does the PIPE icon mean in status bar?(with picture)

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, notification-icons

I just noticed this today, and I have not installed any apps which I think related to this Pipe icon. It just flash and disappear repeatedly but if I pull the status bar there is no visible notification that I can check.

I checked running apps, I cant seem to find any related apps, I only have messenger, tasker, spotify and other system apps. It seems I could not also find any details through google. I already tried rebooting.

Is there anyway to find out this app? perhaps through adb? I have root.[image]

Comment: OOC, what phone is this? That's an unusual-looking notification bar.

Comment: What is OOC? This is [Zenfone 5 2018](https://www.asus.com/Phone/ZenFone-5-ZE620KL/Tech-Specs/).